# How do I improve performance of WPF UserControl rendered in Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, vb.net

We are using `wpf` user controls in windows form like data entry screen with more than 100 Controls. The form rendering time increased after continue usage. Any suggestions?

In Xaml part:

```
Grid Panel to arrange the controls
```

Windows form calling method:

```
Public form As New WPFUserControl
form.Tag = Me
ElementHost1.Child = form
form.Formload()
```

-- more code from comments --

```
Private Sub frmSwitch_New_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 

Public form As New WPFUserControl 
    form.Tag = Me ElementHost1.Child = form 
    form.Formload() 
End Sub
```

Comment: do u ever dispose these new controls ?

Comment: Do not ask the same question multiple times. Please edit your previous question and delete this one.

Comment: @Muds no, i am using datacontext reset only

Comment: @Clemens sry i am new user

Comment: you need to provide us with more code to make your case clear, atleast I cant make much out of given ..

Comment: @Muds in our xmal create <grid> ... </grid> Inside the grid tag me created more than 100 controls(Textbox,Combobox,Checkbox) and arranged them

Comment: i guess your 100 controls are fine, problem is where you create instances of this control and add.. i can  smell controls not being disposed properly

Comment: @Muds yes i think. pls explain how can i dispose the controls properly..

Comment: where is this called from -- Public form As New WPFUserControl

Comment: @Muds in windows form code behind(Form_load Event)

Comment: can we have code please ?

Comment: @Muds Private Sub frmSwitch_New_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Public form As New WPFUserControl
form.Tag = Me
ElementHost1.Child = form
form.Formload()
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instance of you 100s control everytime you call

```
 frmSwitch_New_Load
```

but you never unload new controls created. Just when your frmSwich unloads you need to unload your wpf controls as well

Where you give a call to frmSwitch_New_Load if that's a Load event handler to your form, have an event handler for unload event to that form and underthat event handler unload your current wpf control

Comment: can i make it in UserControl or windows form, any reference link?

Comment: you need to handle formUnload for your windows form.. and there you can Unload your userControl

Comment: Me Handled Unloaded event in user control itself and that place we are disposing data table and data sets only.. Is that correct?? and how can i dispose the controls?

Comment: you need to unload usercontrol in unloaded handler